# tinyMCE move cursor out of tag on double space

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

**SOLVED!**

I am adding SPAN tags to the tinyMCE visual editor to display highlighted text.

while typing within a highlighted span, there may be instances where the cursor becomes trapped... with no way to type out side of the span.

I have created some javascript that fires on a "double space"

the following code...

1.) checks the current cursor position is within my highlighted SPAN

2.) checks the current cursor position is at the end of that SPAN (just before the closing /SPAN)

3.) moves the current cursor from the left of the closing /SPAN to the right of the closing /SPAN

help with any or all will be appreciated.

**the correct code!**

while typing, if you find your self at the end of a SPAN element, pressing the spacebar twice to break out of the current SPAN

```
var mycc = ''
ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, e){
    evt = e || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    // if dbl space
    if(mycc == charCode && charCode==32){
        var curElm = ed.selection.getRng().startContainer;
        var caretPos = ed.selection.getBookmark(curElm.textContent).rng.startOffset;
        // if end of element
        if(caretPos==curElm.textContent.length){
            var mkr = '<span class="marker">!</span>'
            // add marker for cursor positioning
            ed.selection.setContent(mkr)
            var newstr = ''
            // split content at marker (plus ending span for my case)
            var c = ed.getContent({format : 'raw'}).split(" "+mkr+"</span>")
            if(!c[1]){
                c = ed.getContent({format : 'raw'}).split(" "+mkr+"<br></span>")
            }
            // if the conent was split, adjust as needed
            if(c[0]&&c[1]){
                // add closing span back plus marker after
                newstr = c[0]+'</span>'+mkr+c[1]
                // update content
                ed.setContent(newstr)
            }
            // find the marker
            var marker = jQuery(ed.getBody()).find('.marker');
            // set selection
            ed.selection.select(marker.get(0));
            // remove marker
            marker.remove();
        }
    }
    mycc = charCode
})
ed.onMouseDown.add(function(ed, e){
    mycc = ''
})
```

above still works, but i went with the code below. this code breaks out of the end position of a span when pressing the right arow instead of dbl space

enjoy

```
var mycc = ''
ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, e){
    evt = e || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    // if dbl space
    //if(mycc == charCode && charCode==32){
    if(charCode==39){

        var curElm = ed.selection.getRng().startContainer;
        var caretPos = ed.selection.getBookmark(curElm.textContent).rng.startOffset;
        // if end of element
        if(caretPos==curElm.textContent.length){
            var mkr = '<span class="marker">!</span>'
            ed.selection.setContent(mkr)
            var newstr = ''
            var c = ed.getContent({format : 'raw'}).split(mkr+"</span>")
            if(!c[1]){
                c = ed.getContent({format : 'raw'}).split(mkr+"<br></span>")
            }
            if(c[0]&&c[1]){
                newstr = c[0].replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '')+'</span>&nbsp;'+mkr+c[1].replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').replace(/^[\s(&nbsp;]+/g,'')
                ed.setContent(newstr)
                e.preventDefault()  
            }
            var marker = jQuery(ed.getBody()).find('.marker');
            ed.selection.select(marker.get(0));
            marker.remove();
        }
    }
    mycc = charCode
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated my question with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) to see if the current cursor position is within my highlighted SPAN

This is possible

```
var ed = tinymce.get('your_editor_id')
var node = ed.getSelection.getNode(); // in case of complex nestings you will need to loop along the parentNode till you find a span-node

if ($(node).hasClass('highlight')) {...whatever you like..}
```

Comment: Thanks, but BODY is always returned as node while typing